# Вызов переопределенной функции в базовом конструкторе

Tags: c++

Вот нужно достичь примерно этого. Чтобы базовый класс в конструкторе вызвал переопределенную функцию. Кто поможет как нибудь реализовать такой код чтобы полиморфизм сработал.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        createView();
    }

    virtual void createView()
    {
        std::cout << "Base View\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base()
    {

    }

    virtual void createView() override
    {
        std::cout << "Derived View\n";
    }
};

int main()
{

    Base *p = new Derived(); // cout Derived View

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это плохая идея вызывать виртуальные функции в конструкторе. Как вы хотите вызвать функцию класса `Derived`, когда у вас `Base` еще не создан? См. [хорошее правило](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1002058/30/Mayers_-_Effektivnoe_ispolzovanie_CPP.html)

Comment: Я знаю что плохая идея но нужно. Есть идеи как реализовать примерно такое ?

Comment: Оттуда же: *"Есть разные варианты решения этой проблемы. Один из них – сделать функцию logTransaction невиртуальной в классе Transaction, затем потребовать, чтобы конструкторы производного класса передавали необходимую для записи в протокол информацию конструктору Transaction. Эта функция затем могла бы безопасно вызвать невиртуальную logTransaction"*. **Переводя, на ваш случай**: сделать функцию невиртуальной, и передавать ей нужную информацию в качестве параметра.

Comment: Не XY ли это задача? Нужно **зачем**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любая реализация С++ должна вызывать в конструкторе или деструкторе реализацию функции объявленную на уровне текущего класса в иерархии.

Выдержка из [CPP FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors):

> [...]
>
> In a constructor, the virtual call mechanism is disabled because
>    overriding from derived classes hasn’t yet happened. Objects are
>    constructed from the base up, “base before derived”.
>
> [...]
>
> Destruction is done “derived class before base class”, so virtual functions behave as in constructors: Only the local definitions are used – and no calls are made to overriding functions to avoid touching the (now destroyed) derived class part of the object.

Если в двух словах, то в конструкторе виртуальные функции не работают потому что конечный объект **еще** не сконструрован, а в деструкторах - потому что конечный объект **уже** разрушен.

---

Мне на ум приходит три варианта как это зарефакторить.

[**1) Параметризовать функцию, и передать ей всё необходимое**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d791551877a02a32)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base{
public:
    Base(const std::string &str){
        createView(str);
    }

    void createView(const std::string &str){
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived() : 
        Base("Derived View")
    {}
};

int main(){
    Base *p = new Derived();
    delete p;
}
```

**Суть:** нет виртуальных функций - нет проблем.

[**2) Фабричный метод**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f2a41e145b8f857)

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    template<class T>
    static T* construct(){
        T *t = new T;
        t->createView();
        return t;
    }
    virtual void createView(){
        std::cout << "Base View\n";
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    virtual void createView() override{
        std::cout << "Derived View\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Base *p = Base::construct<Derived>();
    delete p;
}
```

**Суть:** вместо конструктора используем метод `construct`, который сначала целиком создаст объект, и только потом начнет вызывать виртуальные функции.

[**3) Конверт/Письмо**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4ce0af5361bac30)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual void createView(){
        std::cout << "Base View\n";
    }
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    Derived() :
        Base()
    {}
    void createView() override{
        std::cout << "Derived View\n";
    }
};

template<class Letter>
class Envelope : public Base{
    std::unique_ptr<Letter> _letter;
public:
    Envelope():
        Base(),
        _letter(new Letter)
    {
        _letter->createView();
    }
    void createView() override{
        _letter->createView();
    }
    ~Envelope(){}
};

int main(){
    Base *p = new Envelope<Derived>();
    delete p;
}
```

**Суть:** тот же фабричный метод ввиде класса. Конверт `Envelope` хранит внутри себя письмо `Derived` и делегирует ему все вызовы виртуальных функций.

Comment: "в конструкторе виртуальные функции не работают"... Вы сначала сказали правильно: "должна вызывать в конструкторе или деструкторе реализацию функции объявленную на уровне текущего класса в иерархии." Виртуальные функции и виртуальный механизм в конструкторе *работают*, но только *вплоть до* текущего уровня иерархии, не ниже. Переопределения сделанные ниже в иерархии - игнорируются.

Comment: @AnT, что Вы имеет в виду под _«виртуальный механизм в конструкторе работают»_? Т.е. понятно, что в стандарте most derived написан, но на практике никакого динамического разрешения не будет, т.е. vptr использоваться не будет, а значит никакой виртуальности.

Comment: @ixSci: Во-первых, единственным способом подавить виртуальность в С++ является использование квалифицированного имени метода в вызове. Во всех остальных случаях вызов виртуального метода является обыкновенным *виртуальным* вызовом. Если компилятор не использует vptr в виртуальном вызове - это не более чем *оптимизация*, основанная на том, что компилятор на этапе компиляции сумел однозначно предсказать, куда приведет vptr. Такая оптимизация обычно используется только в том случае, если виртуальный метод вызывается из конструктора напрямую.

Comment: Но достаточно вызвать виртуальный метод опосредованно (конструктор вызывает метод `a`, а метод `a` уже в свою очередь вызывает какой-то виртуальный метод) как такая оптимизация в общем случае исчезнет и вызов будет делаться через vptr. Также, вызов можно сделать непосредственно из конструктора, но через *указатель* на виртуальный метод - снова будет использоваться vptr. Особенностью работы виртуального механизма в конструкторе является то, что во время работы конструктора класса `T`vptr создаваемого объекта указывает именно на vtbl класса `T`. То есть тип `T` временно является most derived.

Comment: Во всем остальном полиморфизм из конструктора работает так, как он работает всегда - никаких изменений, но с той только разницей, что полиморфизм не будет "видеть" никаких типов, расположенных в иерархии классов ниже конструируемого класса `T`. Вот и все. И еще раз: ваше "vptr использоваться не будет" - это не относящееся к делу замечание. Это не более чем необязательная и ни на что не влияющая оптимизация. Компилятор может (и в ряде случаев будет) делать вызовы из конструктора через vptr. Результат от этого не поменяется: просто полиморфизм будет ограничен в глубину конструируемым классом `T`

Comment: @AnT, ну, ясно, что мы говорим о деталях реализации, частью которой vptr и является, кстати. Ничего не мешает компилятору сделать прямой вызов в непрямых вызовах — у компилятора есть вся информация.

Comment: @xSci: Совершенно верно. Компилятор как правило всегда делают прямой вызов, когда "у компилятора есть вся информация". Конструктор - лишь частный пример такой ситуации.

Comment: @AnT, я об этом и говорю. Из-за этого никакой виртуальности в вызовах в конструкторах/деструкторах нет. Я только об этом. Т.е. я вообще не понимаю, как можно говорить о таких вызовах в контексте виртуальности.

Comment: @ixSci: Еще раз: что такое "вызовы в конструкторах/деструкторах"? Вот пример: `struct B { virtual void foo() {} void bar() { foo(); } }; struct D : B { virtual void foo() {} D() { bar(); } }; struct DD : D { virtual void foo() {} };` Из конструктора `DD::DD()` вызывается конcтруктор `D::D()`. Во время работы конструктора `D::D()` вызывается метод `B::bar()`. Из метода `B::bar()` вызывается метод `foo()`. Управление попадает в `D::foo()`, а не в `B::foo()`. Это - классическая виртуальность, которая сработала во время работы конструктора `D::D()`.

Comment: Но вызвана была `D::foo()`, а не `DD::foo()` - это то ограничение по глубине, о котором я веду речь. Виртуальность, как видите есть и работает прекрасно. Она не работает так, как наивно ожидают новички, но их ожидания совершенно не обоснованы - такой виртуальности им никто никогда и не обещал. Вы же почему-то из этого делаете вывод, что "виртуальность в конструкторе не работает". Это - странный вывод. Это примерно как ожидать, что купив мощный телескоп вы сможете разглядеть на Марсе зеленых человечков. И, не сумев их там разглядеть, прийти к выводу, что телескоп "не работает".